# Doesn't onAppear get called after initializing?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm curious why `ContView` displays

[image]

because, isn't `onAppear` called *after* initializing `ContView`? Shouldn't `filteredCategories` still be `[String]()` and `modifiedTitle` be `""`?

```
struct Options {
    var categories = [String]()
    var title = "Title"
}
struct ParentView: View {
    var options = Options(categories: ["123", "asd", "string"], title: "Some title")
    
    @State var filteredCategories = [String]() /// @State so that I can change the value later
    @State var modifiedTitle = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ContView(categories: filteredCategories, title: modifiedTitle) /// initializing ContView
        .onAppear { /// called after?
                
            var filteredCategories = [String]()
            for category in options.categories { 
                if category.contains("s") { /// this keeps only "asd" and "string"
                    filteredCategories.append(category)
                }
            }
            self.filteredCategories = filteredCategories
            self.modifiedTitle = options.title
        }
    }
}
struct ContView: View {
    var categories: [String] = [String]()
    var title: String = "Support"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("categories: \(categories.count)")
            Text("title: \(title)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. `.onAppear` is called when the view appears (and again, if it re-appeared after a condition became true). The view could be initialized many times (basically, any time the parent's body is recomputed), but if the view itself wasn't hidden previously, then it's not re-appearing, so `.onAppear` isn't called

Comment: Would you explain instead what do you try to achieve? The `why` questions are not productive.

Comment: @Asperi true! I'm making a framework and have an `Options`struct. I put all the configurable options in there, but I need to transfer the values inside to multiple properties (like `ContView`'s `categories` and `title`). I needed a reliable way of transferring the data and wasn't sure if `onAppear` was the right way.